# How to ask forgiveness for bad wish?

Tags: allah

I know i am disturbing you guys a lot and i am sorry for that. But my guilt is just eating me alive. What if someone is harmed because of me? Although I changed my speech immediately after wishing for woman getting cheated on. I changed my speech within 7-10 seconds, i am still afraid. Please guide me. Will i go through the same?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry it’s ok your asking a question about ur religion NEVER DESPAIR FROM ALLAHS MERCY EVER. No matter what you have done repent to Allah and promise never to do it again and Ramadan is coming up you are never gonna get closer to Allah then Ramadan. One of Shaitan’s largest plans is to make you think in ur head I sinned to much and there is no hope from me I am done. NEVER THINK THAT WAY EVER remember this run to Allah and repent and he will forgive you if you are sincere and remorseful in the repentance.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: I am worried i will go though the same. Is there any way that i won't have to go though this? Please help.

Comment: If you go through the same repent again and again and again Allah’s forgiveness is unlimited never stops with a sincere repentance.

Answer (score 0):

My brother,

Allah is Forgiving and Merciful, and He is Welcoming to repentance, so ask Allah for forgiveness, during this blessed month and especially continue afterwards and InchaAllah God will forgive you.
And my brother, it is a good thing that you make your own judgement in this life, it is a blessing. And never doubt that the greatness of Allah's Mercy.